# How to handle multiple languages in AngularJS for form validation messages / alerts?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to develop an app using AngularJS which should work in multiple, user selected languages. I put my views in `views/en` and `views/fr`, etc, so if a user is viewing in English, then the template URL for all controllers will be `views/en/someFile.html`, and for French it would be `/views/fr/someFile.html`, and so on.

The question is, how can I handle displaying random form validation messages / alerts which are displayed by javascript, to be displayed in the correct language?

E.g in all my controllers I have a `$scope.title` variable which sets the `<title>` in the browser. If the user selects a different language, I want the `<title>` to be updated to be shown in his selected language as well.

What's the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to separate your mark-up from your textual data? At the moment you are repeating your mark-up across language folders. Separating the concerns of textual data and markup would open opportunities for inserting textual data conditionally.

If your fishing for a conditional template solution, you might check out ui-router. Head on over to https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates. templateUrl can be set to a function returning the location of a template, but you'll have to get to grips with ui-router!

Comment: @IanHaggerty the templates are being generated dynamically and then put in those files by a caching system. So that's taken care of. I only want to know how I would dynamically change javascript variables, e.g `$scope.title` based on the language selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [textService](https://github.com/iahag001/Angular-Text-Service)

I have updated this answer to reflect my current solution to this problem. Removing the textual data dependence in templates is an important problem I feel and I have gone ahead and wrote my own little module for this. If you want to use all the text insertion options (state text and relative text), you'll need to use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), to configure your routes.

Here's the usage. I'll put the module at the end of the answer.

Include text-service.js after angular, but before your module definition

Declare it as a dependency: `angular.module("app", ["textService"]`

Bind a text data object to it. The text data object should mimic your state hierarchy. e.g.:

```
var textData = {
  home: { // 'home' state
    // text data for home state here
    child { // 'home.child' state
      // text data for child state
    }
  }
}
```

Text objects should be object literals with the language names as keys:

```
var textData = {
  home: {
      title: {
        en: "Home",
        fr: "Maison"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Set the language and bind the text object to textService:

```
app.run(function(textService) {
  var textData = ...
  textService
    .setLanguage("en")
    .bindText(textData)
});
```

Having all the text data inside the run function may not be desirable - so it is up to the user if they want to use a factory or a number of factories to inject this:

```
app.factory("textData", function() {
  var textData = ...
  return textData
}
app.run(function(textService, textData) {
  textService
    .setLanguage("en")
    .bindText(textData)
});
```

There are four attribute based directives for retrieving text from your templates. The attribute names are:

1. `atext` - "Absolute Text"
2. `stext` - "State Text"
3. `rtext` - "Relative Text"
4. `text` - "Text"

To use from a template, add, say, `atext` as an attribute and set its value to a string locating the text data your interested in:

```
<h1 atext="home.title.en"></h1>
```

All the directives will replace the innerHtml of whatever DOM element you add it to with the text data, so make sure it has no children DOM elements you care about.

The differences in the directives are primarily to do with locating the text strings. Suppose we had the following text data object:

```
var textData = {
  title: {
    en: "Index",
    fr: "Index"
  },
  // home state
  home: {
    title: {en: "Home",fr: "Maison"},
    header: {en: "Heading", fr: ""}
    child: { // home.child
      title: {en: "Child",fr: "Enfant"},
        intro: {
          en: "Welcome to child",
          fr: "Bienvenue à l'enfant"
        }
    }
    lonelychild: {
      // no text data
    }
  }
};
```

`atext` refers to the absolute location of the string. So `atext="title.en"` fetches "Index" where as `atext="title"` would throw an error (for now).

`stext` refers to a string relative to the current state. For example, if in state 'home', `stext="title"` fetches "Home". If you weren't in any state at all, it would fetch "Index". And if you were to navigate to 'home.child' state, it would fetch "Child". (note: these are all provided you have set the language to "en")

`rtext` refers to a relative text location. It behaves just like `stext` except it will search up the state heirarchy looking for textual data to match as well. This is very handy for dynamically changing the title depending on state:

```
<title rtext="title"></title>
```

This will replace the innerHtml of the title DOM element with the nearest 'title' text data. So if you were in the state 'home.lonelychild' the title would still bind to "Home" (because it is in the parent state's text data).

`text` This directive works just like `atext`, except you don't need to specify the language.

The directives which change dynamically on language change are stext, rtext and text.
You can change the language using, for e.g., `textService.setLanguage("fr")`. This will $broadcast a "languageChange" event to all the text directives indicating that they should update. If you want to suppress the update, pass a second parameter indicating whether an update should be done: `textService.setLanguage("fr", false)`/

The directives which change dynamically on state change are stext and rtext.

You can force an update using `textService.update()`

I've gone to some lengths to make this plugin as fast as possible. As a general rule of thumb, each text directive will incur an initial processing time of about 1ms. I think much of this bulk comes from angular initialising a directive for each piece of text data. But following that, the dynamic updates are quick, even if you have a 100 or so text directives on a one page.

---

Here's the module and a link to the [github repo](https://github.com/iahag001/Angular-Text-Service)

```
/*
 * text-service.js
 * Author: Ian Haggerty - iahag001@yahoo.co.uk
 * Last Edit: 17/08/2013
 */

angular.module("textService", [])
    .factory("textService", function ($rootScope, $log) {

        /* Internal Implementation */
        var textService;
        textService = {
            language: "",
            state: "",
            textData: {},

            /* text(request) - Text request
             * @request Absolute path to text without language appended - e.g. 'home.title'
             */
            text: function (request) {
                return (new Function(
                    "return arguments[0].textData." + request +
                        ((textService.language) ? ("." + textService.language) : "")
                ))(textService);
            },

            /* absText(request)- Absolute text request
             * @request Absolute path to text with language appended - e.g. 'home.title.en'
             */
            absText: function (request) {
                return (new Function(
                    "return arguments[0].textData." + request
                ))(textService);
            },

            /* relText(request, cut) - Scoped text request, will search up the state heirarchy
             * @request Relative path to text without language appended - e.g. 'title'
             * @state State to test for textual data - defaults to the current state, used recursively
             */
            relText: function (request, state) {
                if(state === undefined) {
                    // initial call to function
                    state = textService.state
                }
                try { return textService.text((state?state+".":"") + request)}
                catch(e) {
                    if(!state) return "" // terminate to avoid infinite recursion
                    return textService.relText(request, state.split(".")).slice(0,-1).join(".");
                }
            },

            /* stateText - request a string in the current state(e.g. stateText('title')
             * @request - Relative path to string in current state
             */
            stateText: function (request) {
                return (textService.state) ?
                    textService.text(textService.state + "." + request) : "";
            }
        }

        // Register handler for state changes
        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function (event, toState) {
            textService.state = toState.name;
        });

        /* Public API */
        var textServiceApi = {
            /* bindText - Bind the entire textual data to a new object
             * @textData - The text data object to be bound to
             */
            bindText: function (textData) {
                textService.textData = textData;
                $rootScope.$broadcast("textDataChange")
                return textServiceApi;
            },
            /* setText() - function to set textual data and update text directives
             * @request The request string, e.g. 'home.title', 'home.title.en'
             * @textData The textual data. Could be a literal string or an object with textual data
             * @doUpdate Boolean indicating whether to update text directives. Defaults to FALSE.
             * Example usage 1: setText('home.title.en', "Title") - set a text string without update
             * Example usage 2: setText('home.title', {en:"Title", fr:"Maison"}, true)
             * - set a text object with update to the page
             */
            setText: function(request, textData, doUpdate) {
                (new Function(
                    "arguments[0].textData." + request + "=arguments[1]"
                ))(textService, textData)
                if(!doUpdate) $rootScope.$broadcast("textDataChange")
                return textServiceApi
            },
            /* getText() - Function returning textual data
             * @request An absolute reference to the text
             * Example usage: getText('home.title.en'), getText('home.title') // this returns a text object
             */
            getText: function(request) {
                if(!request)
                    return textService.textData
                else {
                    return (new Function(
                        "return arguments[0].textData." + request
                    ))(textService)
                }
            },
            /* setLanguage() - Set the current language
             * @langauge  - The new language. e.g. "fr", "en"
             * @doUpdate - Boolean indicating whether to update text directives, defaults to TRUE
             * Example usage: setLanguage("fr") // change to french and update the page
             */
            setLanguage: function (language, doUpdate) {
                if(doUpdate === undefined) doUpdate = true;
                textService.language = language
                $rootScope.$broadcast("languageChange")
                return textServiceApi;
            },
            getLanguage: function () {
                return textService.language;
            },
            /* update() - Requests all text directives to update themselves
             */
            update: function() {
                $rootScope.$broadcast("textDataChange")
                return textServiceApi
            },
            /* Used by text directives */
            text: textService.text,
            absText: textService.absText,
            relText: textService.relText,
            stateText: textService.stateText
        }
        return textServiceApi
    })
    /* Text directive */
    .directive("text", function (textService) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                function update() {
                    element.html(textService.text(attrs.text))
                }

                scope.$on("languageChange", update)
                scope.$on("textDataChange", update)

                update()
            }
        }
    })
    /* Absolute text directive */
    .directive("atext", function (textService) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                function update() {
                    element.html(textService.absText(attrs.atext))
                }

                scope.$on("textDataChange", update)

                update()
            }
        }
    })
    /* State text directive */
    .directive("stext", function (textService) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                function update() {
                    element.html(textService.stateText(attrs.stext))
                }

                scope.$on("languageChange", update)
                scope.$on("textDataChange", update)
                scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", update)

                update()
            }
        }
    })
    /* Relative text directive */
    .directive("rtext", function (textService, $log) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                function update(event, request) {
                    element.html(textService.relText(attrs.rtext))
                }

                scope.$on("languageChange", update)
                scope.$on("textDataChange", update)
                scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", update)

                update()
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: I can't really set up a service for every single string that I need to have a translation for, e.g `titleProvider, firstNameRequiredProvider, emailInvalidProvider, closeThisBoxProvider`, it will grow ridiculous pretty quickly. Any other ideas?

Comment: Stick all the data in one service object :)

You can even invent your own little syntax for example

globals.home.title.fr

Where globals is the service object injected.

Comment: If you wanna change your answer to how such a service might be used, I can accept!